# WCF method name is not showing up when running the application

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

I am developing a WCF web service. I have created a service and when I run the service, I do not see any methods listed.

I have attached screenshot:

[image: Missing method name]

This is the service and methods I have created:

XML request

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <opportunityID>1-1DA7KN</opportunityID>
 <opportunityStatus>Created</opportunityStatus>
 <opportunityserviceType>LEASE_REQUEST</opportunityserviceType>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOpportunity
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
     UriTemplate = "postmethod/updateOpportunity")]
    bool updateOpportunity(opportunityActivity obj);
}

[DataContract]
public class opportunityActivity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityStatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityserviceType { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RayaSoapService.Opportunity">
        <endpoint address="" contract="RayaSoapService.IOpportunity" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test_ROLSP_DB_V1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ModelModel.csdl|res://*/Model.ModelModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.ModelModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.210;initial catalog=Test_ROLSP_DB_V1;user id=sa;password=123@root;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Above code works fine. I tested it using web client. Now I want to expose this to some third party so I should give them xml format. I am not able to figure out how to get xml format for the above service? Whenever I run the service I am not able to see method listed on the page also. Can someone help me to get xml for the above request? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you can post app.config end points,it will be clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add MEX endpoint behavior configuration,I think you have missed it.

```
    <services>
      <service name="RayaSoapService.Opportunity" 
 behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" contract="RayaSoapService.IOpportunity" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Thank you. i have posted my web.config file. May i know what i am missing in the above code?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole modified according to your web.config file.

Comment: Thank you Hameed. i have added and it is running without errors. But i am not getting any method names listed.

Comment: Try with Https mex also.

Comment: Where should i add https? binding="basicHttpsBinding"?

Comment: May i know how can i create xml request for the above service?

Comment: When i tried from postman i got the below error. The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring>

Comment: I meant Try  with this attribute <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" />  also.